# If $f$ meromorphic and $f\not = 0$, show that $\frac{1}{f}$ is meromorphic. Proof verification.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Would someone please verify this proof.

Please be *critical*, I still find it quite difficult to write proofs.

> If $f$ meromorphic in open $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and $f\not = 0$, show that $\displaystyle\frac{1}{f}$ is meromorphic op $\Omega$.

### Proof:

Since $f\not = 0$ there won't appear any new isolated singular points. Some  of the isolated singularities of $f$ may disappear.

Take one of the singularities and call it $z_0$.

- If $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ then $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{1}{f(z)} = 0$.

  In other words: if $z_0$ was a pole of $f$ then $z_0$ is a zero or a removable singularity of $\frac{1}{f}$.
- If $z_0$ is a removable singularity and $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = 0$ then $\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{1}{f(z)} = \infty$ meaning $z_0$ is a pole of $\frac{1}{z_0}$.
- If $z_0$ is a removable singularity and $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = A \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{ 0\}$ then $\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{1}{f(z)} = \frac{1}{A}$. In which case $z_0$ would remain removable.